# Spritekit skaction scaleby causes node to disappear

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have been trying to use a scaleBy action in Spritekit and have been getting an odd result as the node disappears when tapping the screen, it should stay forever. The label is just there to see how long it takes. I've tried on a device/ simulator.
I think it could be because I don't use another action to reverse the size but  change it to a specific size, as this is the size I want but i'm not sure.

It's just a simple piece of code after a while the node disappears,  does anyone know why? and how can I change the code to stop it from disappearing so I can use the Skaction scaleby feature.   I have given all the code so you can try it out. Thanks

Here's all the code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


`let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
  var timerSecs = 8.5
  var setScaleXY = 8.0
  let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
  var tapped : Int = 0 {
    didSet{
      label.text = "\(tapped)"
  }
  }
  var action = SKAction()

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
    label.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 500)
    label.fontColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    addChild(label)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y:    frame.size.height / 2)
    sprite.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    self.addChild(sprite)


    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            sprite.removeAllActions()
            sprite.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

        }
    }



 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   action = SKAction.scaleBy(CGFloat(self.setScaleXY), duration: self.timerSecs)
   tapped += 1

changeSize()
   sprite.runAction(action)

 }



func changeSize() {
    if tapped == 2 {
      setScaleXY = 20.0
    } else if tapped < 10 {
      setScaleXY = 15.0
    }

    else if tapped > 20 {
      setScaleXY = 25.0
    }
    else if tapped > 40 {
      setScaleXY = 15.0
    }
    else {
      setScaleXY = 20.0
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are scaling way to big it looks like, I mean the smallest scale size will scale by 15 for 60 times per second for 8.5 seconds  that is a scale of 7650 as your end result.  This means your sprite is 459,000 x 459,000 in size

Comment: So scaling can only be used to a certain size and then if it is too big it removes the node ?

Comment: The node is way to big to fit into memory. Why on earth would you ever need a node 459,000 x 459,000 points

Comment: Ok,but I have adjusted the scale to less than 4.0 but it still disappears.

Comment: No idea what you mean by that

Comment: nevermind,  the 'by' commands do something different here,  they only move to the given value in the duration,  so your issue is not scaling,  no idea what is wrong